# Why does Panels output <section> for some panes and <div> for others?

Tags: 7, panels, chaos-tool-suite, theming

I'm just wondering what causes Panels Pages (or cTools pages? Never figured out which is which) to output some panel panes in a `<section>` html tag wrapper, and output the other panel panes in a `<div>` html tag wrapper?

I would prefer it if they were one or the other, but not both. So I wanted to understand and find out the reason so I could potentially make it consistent.

**Theme I use:** AdaptiveTheme (Custom Sub-theme with minimal configurations and changes)

**Panels "Variant" Layout:** AT One Column (Responsive single column panel layout, AdaptiveTheme core)

[image]

Comment: The "pages" concept comes from the module "Page manager", which is a part of ctools. Panels however is usually used to render them. So you could say both "Panels Pages" or "cTools pages", but they would mean slightly different things. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Panels contains no instances of `<section>`. This comes entirely from your theme.

Specifically, I believe it's from `at_core/templates/panels-pane.tpl.php` which contains the following:

```
 * Adaptivetheme variables:
 * - $is_mobile: Bool, requires the Browscap module to return TRUE for mobile
 *   devices. Use to test for a mobile context.
 * - $tag: top level wrapper element, section or div.
```

followed by

```
 <<?php print $tag . $attributes . $id; ?>>
```

The relevant logic appears to be

```
/**
 * Preprocess variables for panels_pane.tpl.php
 */
function adaptivetheme_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars) {
  // Top level wrapper
  $vars['tag'] = $vars['title'] ? 'section' : 'div';
```

Comment: So it depends if the pane has a title or not, and that causes it to output either `<section>` or `<div>`. Weird logic, doesn't make any sense to me in terms of semantics. Thanks.

Comment: It does depend on that yes, but that's just adaptive's logic. Panels itself doesn't care, and you are of course free to override the behavior.